# Strange issue with Youtube API video don't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on a template on my project, it is not in a server just working local on my machine, the strange issue i get is, i have a page that comes with the template and there is the video background template working very well.
When i copie the code to my index page exactly how it is, it doesn't work, the video doesn't start and i get this error:

```
VM5155:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js:8)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.js:136)
    at m.fn.init.buildPlayer (jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js:8)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (functions.js:1565)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.js:136)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (functions.js:1562)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
(anonymous) @ jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js:8
each @ jquery.js:384
each @ jquery.js:136
buildPlayer @ jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js:8
(anonymous) @ functions.js:1565
each @ jquery.js:384
each @ jquery.js:136
(anonymous) @ functions.js:1562
j @ jquery.js:3148
fireWith @ jquery.js:3260
ready @ jquery.js:3472
J @ jquery.js:3503
```

i don't get it why i get the error in the index page and i don't have it on the other page, the script order is exactly the same, here is the code that i have related to the video:

```
<section class="content_section bg_fixed white_section bg2">
    <div class="bg_overlay">
        <!-- Video -->
        <div class="youtube_bg_video has_overlay now_pausing" data-property="data-property=" {
            "videoURL:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6_85cSOIcE',containment:'self',startAt:0,mute:true,autoPlay:true,loop:false,opacity:1,showYTLogo:false, realfullscreen:false, quality:'small'}"></div>
    <!-- End Video -->

<div class="content row_spacer clearfix">
    <!-- Video Frame-->
    <div class="video_frame centered">
        <div class="video_frame_tl">
            <div class="video_frame_br">
                <div class="video_frame_bl row_spacer2">
                    <div class="main_title upper">
                        <h2><span class="line"></span>Video Background</h2>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="play_video_btn pause_video">
                        <span><i class="ico-pause2"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Video Frame-->
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the script order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.videobackground.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- this is where we put our custom functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- this is where we put our custom functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

why is that happening someoene know something about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Youtube `iFrame` embed code.

Comment: well i want a video without propagand, muted, and with autplay, without the youtube icon is that possivel?

Comment: If you search for HTML5 video display, you may find something. But that process is not very complete. You can use embed codes from youtube or other platform that uses them such as Vimeo